# Using dplyr, how to pipe or chain to plot()?

Tags: r, plot, dplyr, piping

I am new to dplyr() package and trying to use it for my visualization assignment. I am able to pipe my data to **ggplot()** but unable to do that with **plot()**. I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467992/how-to-use-chaining-in-dplyr-to-access-internal-variables) and the answers including the one in comments, didn't work for me.

Code 1:

```
emission <- mynei %>%
    select(Emissions, year) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarise (total=sum(Emissions))

emission %>%
    plot(year, total,.)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in plot(year, total, emission) : object 'year' not found
```

Code 2:

```
mynei %>%
    select(Emissions, year) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarise (total=sum(Emissions))%>%
    plot(year, total, .)
```

This didn't work either and returned the same error.

Interestingly, the solution from the post I mentioned works for the same dataset but doesn't work out for my own data. However, I am able to create the plot using **emission$year** and **emission$total**.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: As shown in the answer to the question you linked, it is `plot.formula` that has the `data` argument.  So you'd need to use `plot(total ~ year, .)`.

Comment: This also works without specifying the `.` - so you could use e.g.  `plot(total ~ year)`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`plot.default` doesn't take a data argument, so your best bet is to pipe to `with`:

```
mynei %>%
    select(Emissions, year) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarise (total=sum(Emissions))%>%
    with(plot(year, total))
```

In case anyone missed @aosmith's comment on the question, `plot.formula` *does* have a data argument, but of course the `formula` is the first argument so we need to use the `.` to put the data in the right place. So another option is

```
... %>%
  plot(total ~ year, data = .)
```

Of course, `ggplot` takes `data` as the first argument, so to use `ggplot` do:

```
... %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = total)) + geom_point()
```

`lattice::xyplot` is like`plot.formula`: there is a data argument, but it's not first, so:

```
... %>% 
  xyplot(total ~ year, data = .)
```

Just look at the documentation and make sure you use a `.` if `data` isn't the first argument. If there's no `data` argument at all, using `with` is a good work-around.

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative, you can use the `%$%` operator from `magrittr` to be able to access the columns of a dataframe directly. For example:

```r
iris %$%
  plot(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width)
```

This is useful many times when you need to feed the result of a `dplyr` chain to a base R function (such as `table`, `lm`, `plot`, etc). It can also be used to extract a column from a dataframe as a vector, e.g.:

`iris %>% filter(Species=='virginica') %$% Sepal.Length`

This is the same as:

`iris %>% filter(Species=='virginica') %>% pull(Sepal.Length)`