# ggSave group_by df list of ggarrange'd ggplot objects

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, pipe, magrittr

I've used `group_by`, `do`, and `ggplot` - twice - to create two simple `dfs` of Date (the group) and a list of the `ggplot` outputs, thanks hugely to help from examples on this site. Simplified example:

```
p1 <- df_i %>% group_by(Date) %>% do(
plots = ggplot(data = .) +
geom_line() #etc, hugely long and detailed ggplot call omitted for brevity, but it works fine
) # close do
```

I can then join those `dfs`,

```
p1 <- cbind(p1, p2[,2])
names(p1) <- c("Date", "Temp", "Light") #Temp & Light were both "plots" from above
```

And loop through the rows, saving the outputs in a 1-row (top & bottom object) `ggarranged` `png`:

```
for (j in 1:nrow(p1)) { 
      ggsave(file = paste0(p1$Date[j], ".png"),
             plot = arrangeGrob(p1$Temp[[j]], p1$Light[[j]]),
             device="png",scale=1.75,width=6.32,height=4,units="in",dpi=300,limitsize=TRUE)
}
```

So far, so good. But nature abhors a `for-loop`, so I was trying to do the `ggsaving` in a `group_by`, using the same `ggsave` parameter options, changing only what's needed given the difference in `for-loop` indexing vs (what I understand of) `group_by` subsetting:

```
p1 %>% group_by(Date) %>%
      ggsave(file = paste0(.$Date, ".png"),
             plot = arrangeGrob(Temp, Light),...) #other params hidden here for brevity
```

> Error in grDevices::png(..., res = dpi, units = "in"): invalid
>   'pointsize' argument

If I add `pointsize=10` it says "invalid bg value"; add `bg = "white"`:

> Error in check.options(new, name.opt = ".X11.Options", envir =
>   .X11env) :    invalid arguments in 'grDevices::png(..., res = dpi,
>   units = "in")' (need named args)

(I also tried lowering `dpi` to no effect). Possibly I'm going about this the wrong way, e.g. swapping `%>%` for `%$%` in [Vlad's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51437434/3975144) from `magrittr`:

```
Error in gList(list(list(data = list(DateTimeUTCmin5 = c(915213660, 915213780,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
```

This gives the same error with `Date` and `.$Date` in the `ggsave` call. Trying to recreate the `do` framework:

```
 p1 %>% group_by(Date) %>%
      do(ggsave(file = paste0(.$Date, ".png"),"_", .$Date, ".png"),
             plot = arrangeGrob(Temp, Light), #etc
```

> Error in arrangeGrob(Temp, Light) : object 'Temp' not found

```
p1 %>% group_by(Date) %>%
      do(ggsave(file = paste0(.$Date, ".png"),"_", .$Date, ".png"),
             plot = arrangeGrob(.$Temp, .$Light), #etc
```

> Error in gList(list(list(data = list(DateTimeUTCmin5 = c(915213660,
>   915213780,  :    only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"

Which gives the same error if I use `%$%`.

Does anyone have the connected stack of understanding of these tools such that they can see what I'm doing wrong here? It seems like I should be close, but I'm increasingly groping around in the dark. Any pointers very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Equally if folks recommend a different approach I'm interested too. It strikes me that I could use an `lapply` (or `parSapply`) instead of the `for-loop` on the `p1` `df`. Do operations on `grouped dfs` outperform `apply` operations?

[Edit: desired final output: ggsave dumps 1 image (with 2 plots on it) per Date, into the specified folder. Essentially if I can get ggsave to work within the grouped_df, that should be that]

Comment: Can you describe what you wish your final output to be?

Comment: oh, yes, sorry, added now