# Shape click event with several layers

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to load data on two different plots by clicking on polygons from two different maps.

I would like the user to be able to load the plot in the first tab by clicking on one of the polygon of the first map. Same thing if he clicks on one of the polygons in the second tab.

My attempt:

```
   ###Reprodutible code:

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)
    
        #Creation of dummy polygon 1:
            Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
            Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))
            Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
            Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")
            SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2), 1:2)
            SpPDF <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpP, data = data.frame(x=1:length(SpP)), match.ID = F)
            Extent = extent(SpPDF)
            SpPDF$shapefile_ID<-1:nrow(SpPDF)
            
        
            #Creation of dummy polygon 2:
            SrA = Polygon(cbind(c(12,24,25,45,65),c(45,65,41,22,33)))
            SrB = Polygon(cbind(c(55,45,25,55),c(25,35,25,25)))
            SrsA = Polygons(list(SrA), "sA")
            SrsB = Polygons(list(SrB), "sB")
            SpP2 = SpatialPolygons(list(SrsA,SrsB), 1:2)
            SpPDF2 <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpP2, data = data.frame(x=1:length(SpP2)), match.ID = F)
            Extent = extent(SpPDF2)
            SpPDF2$shapefile_ID<-1:nrow(SpPDF2)
            
        
        #Creation of dummy dataframe 1:
            shapefile_ID <- c('1','2')
            x<- c(10, 20)
            y <- c(145, 412)
            
            test1 <- data.frame(shapefile_ID, x,y)
            
        
        #Creation of dummy dataframe 1:
            shapefile_ID <- c('1','2')
            x2<- c(4, 8)
            y2 <- c(12, 154)
            test2 <- data.frame(shapefile_ID, x2,y2)
            
            
            ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title="test"),dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("test", tabname="test"))),dashboardBody(
             fluidRow(
                                     box(title = "Test",
                                         width = 12,
                                         status = "info",
                                         solidHeader = T, 
                                         collapsible = F,
                                         tabBox(id = "window1", width = 12, 
                                                tabPanel("tab1", fluidRow( 
                                                  column(width = 5, leafletOutput(outputId = "test_map", height = 500)), 
                                                  column(width = 7, plotOutput(outputId = "plot1", height = 500) 
                                                         ),
                                                )),
                                                
                                                tabPanel("tab2", fluidRow( 
                                                  column(width = 5, leafletOutput(outputId = "test_map2", height = 500)), 
                                                  column(width = 7, plotOutput(outputId = "plot2", height = 500), 
                                                         
                                                
                                                ))))))))
                                               
            
            
            server <- function(input, output, session) {
       
              ### --------------------------------
              rv <- reactiveVal()
              
              output$test_map<-renderLeaflet(
                leaflet() %>%
                  setView(1.23, 5.42, zoom = 4) %>%
                  addTiles()  %>% 
                  addPolygons(data=SpPDF, 
                              fillColor = "blue",
                              weight = 2,
                              opacity = 1,
                              color = "blue",
                              dashArray = "3",
                              fillOpacity = 0.3,
                              highlight = highlightOptions(
                                weight = 5,
                                color = "#666",
                                dashArray = "",
                                fillOpacity = 0.7,
                                bringToFront = TRUE,
                              layerId = ~shapefile_ID)   
                 ))
              
              observeEvent(input$test_map_shape_click, {
                rv(input$test_map_shape_click$id)
              })
    
              output$test_map2<-renderLeaflet(
                leaflet() %>%
                  setView(5.33, 45.6, zoom = 2) %>%
                  addTiles()  %>% 
                  addPolygons(data=SpPDF2, 
                              fillColor = "blue",
                              weight = 2,
                              opacity = 1,
                              color = "blue",
                              dashArray = "3",
                              fillOpacity = 0.3,
                              highlight = highlightOptions(
                                weight = 5,
                                color = "#666",
                                dashArray = "",
                                fillOpacity = 0.7,
                                bringToFront = TRUE,
                                layerId = ~shapefile_ID)))
                  
              
              observeEvent(input$test_map2_shape_click, {
                rv(input$test_map2_shape_click$id)
              })
    
              
              output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
                if (is.null(rv())) return (NULL)
                test1 %>%
                  filter(shapefile_ID == rv()) %>%
                plot(x = x, y = y)
     
              })
                
              output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
                if (is.null(rv())) return (NULL)
                test2 %>%
                  filter(shapefile_ID == rv()) %>%
                  plot(x = x, y = y)
       
              })
                
            }
              
              
        shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Could someone help me with this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things not working :

- layerId should be an argument of addPolygons() function, not highlightOptions()
- plot() function cannot go in dplyr pipes as is ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940568/using-dplyr-how-to-pipe-or-chain-to-plot))

Full code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(tidyverse)
library(leaflet)

#Creation of dummy polygon 1:
Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))
Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2), 1:2)
SpPDF <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpP, data = data.frame(x=1:length(SpP)), match.ID = F)
Extent = extent(SpPDF)
SpPDF$shapefile_ID<-1:nrow(SpPDF)


#Creation of dummy polygon 2:
SrA = Polygon(cbind(c(12,24,25,45,65),c(45,65,41,22,33)))
SrB = Polygon(cbind(c(55,45,25,55),c(25,35,25,25)))
SrsA = Polygons(list(SrA), "sA")
SrsB = Polygons(list(SrB), "sB")
SpP2 = SpatialPolygons(list(SrsA,SrsB), 1:2)
SpPDF2 <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpP2, data = data.frame(x=1:length(SpP2)), match.ID = F)
Extent = extent(SpPDF2)
SpPDF2$shapefile_ID<-1:nrow(SpPDF2)


#Creation of dummy dataframe 1:
shapefile_ID <- c('1','2')
x<- c(10, 20)
y <- c(145, 412)

test1 <- data.frame(shapefile_ID, x,y)


#Creation of dummy dataframe 1:
shapefile_ID <- c('1','2')
x2<- c(4, 8)
y2 <- c(12, 154)
test2 <- data.frame(shapefile_ID, x2,y2)


ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title="test"),dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("test", tabname="test"))),dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    box(title = "Test",
        width = 12,
        status = "info",
        solidHeader = T, 
        collapsible = F,
        tabBox(id = "window1", width = 12, 
               tabPanel("tab1", fluidRow( 
                 column(width = 5, leafletOutput(outputId = "test_map", height = 500)), 
                 column(width = 7, plotOutput(outputId = "plot1", height = 500) 
                 ),
               )),
               
               tabPanel("tab2", fluidRow( 
                 column(width = 5, leafletOutput(outputId = "test_map2", height = 500)), 
                 column(width = 7, plotOutput(outputId = "plot2", height = 500), 
                        
                        
                 ))))))))



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ### --------------------------------
  rv <- reactiveVal()
  
  output$test_map<-renderLeaflet(
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(1.23, 5.42, zoom = 4) %>%
      addTiles()  %>% 
      addPolygons(data=SpPDF, 
                  layerId = ~shapefile_ID,
                  fillColor = "blue",
                  weight = 2,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "blue",
                  dashArray = "3",
                  fillOpacity = 0.3,
                  highlight = highlightOptions(
                    weight = 5,
                    color = "#666",
                    dashArray = "",
                    fillOpacity = 0.7,
                    bringToFront = TRUE
                    )   
      ))
  
  observeEvent(input$test_map_shape_click, {
    rv(input$test_map_shape_click$id)
  })
  
  output$test_map2<-renderLeaflet(
    leaflet() %>%
      setView(5.33, 45.6, zoom = 2) %>%
      addTiles()  %>% 
      addPolygons(data=SpPDF2, 
                  layerId = ~shapefile_ID,
                  fillColor = "blue",
                  weight = 2,
                  opacity = 1,
                  color = "blue",
                  dashArray = "3",
                  fillOpacity = 0.3,
                  highlight = highlightOptions(
                    weight = 5,
                    color = "#666",
                    dashArray = "",
                    fillOpacity = 0.7,
                    bringToFront = TRUE)))
  
  
  observeEvent(input$test_map2_shape_click, {
    rv(input$test_map2_shape_click$id)
  })
  
  observe(print(rv()))
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(rv())) return (NULL)
    test1 %>%
      filter(shapefile_ID == rv()) %>%
      with(plot(x = x, y = y))
    
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(rv())) return (NULL)
    test2 %>%
      filter(shapefile_ID == rv()) %>%
      with(plot(x = x, y = y))
    
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```